# Place image on top of keywords

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsing

Let's say I have a div:

```
<div id="mainContent">some random text. bla bla bla.</div>
```

let's say that the keword in this example is the word `random`. how could I place an image on top of that word?

In other words I will have to find that div with JavaScript then use a regular expression to find the keyword and then maybe wrap that keyword inside a span placing an img tag inside with it's position set to absolute.

I guess the hardest part in this is warping the keyword with a span?

### edit

moreover how could I place the image on the center of the word? do I have to wrap it on a table instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, store the contents of the div with:

```
var x = document.getElementById('abc').innerHTML;
```

Then, use regex to replace the keyword with span wrapped version.

```
var keyword = "test";
x.replace(keyword, "<span>"+keyword+"</span>");
```

Then swap it back in;

```
document.getElementById('abc').innerHTML = x;
```

I think using this would be better:

```
x.replace('\b'+ keyword +'\b', "<span>"+keyword+"</span>");
```

\b match a word boundary.

Answer (score 0):

For the answer you accepted, you have to know the id of the div that has the keyword. This solution is a bit more dynamic and uses jquery to find all divs with your keyword so you could  place images on all of them.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/flynfish/5KfHg/)

```
var keyword = "random";
var found = $('div:contains("' + keyword +'")');

$.each(found, function(){
    var wrapper = '<span class="whatever">' + keyword + '</span>';
    var oldHtml = $(this).html();

    $(this).html(oldHtml.replace(keyword, wrapper));

});
```